# Boss taking forever to check my work

Tags: management, workload

My boss said he wanted to look at my code before I can test it on the system for our company. 3 weeks ago he said he will look over the weekend. Last week I asked him again and he said he will look at it over the weekend and last weekend has passed and still no word.

Meanwhile I ask him what I should do in the meantime and he doesn't really have an answer. What should I do in this situation? Is he just busy or is he trying to get rid of me somehow? This guy recently got promoted to management.

Comment: If you have other developers with the same boss, do they encounter this issue as well? If all their code reviews are getting turned around in 24 hours and yours take weeks, that's a pretty different situation to if your boss is well known for taking ages to review.

Answer (score 8):

> What should I do in this situation?

Send a reminder every week by mail and ask him if he was able to review your code. In the meanwhile you could make yourself useful by:

- review it yourself and see if you can improve bits 'n pieces
- write test-cases or implement automated testing
- write documentation regarding your code and it's functionality
- maybe write a user manual
- improve your skills by solving some code-challenges

> Is he just busy or is he trying to get rid of me somehow?

Since you mentioned that he just recently got promoted into his new manager-role, he might just be busy settling in and following up to his tasks and duties - I wouldn't read too much into it..

Comment: @pia What makes you think that he dislikes or even hates you? Does he show signs of resentment towards you?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to write him a new email in which you use a combination of the following three strategies.

- Make it really easy for him to take a quick look at your code. For example provide a link to the relevant shelveset/branch in the email, or put the changed procedures/functions in the email with the changes highlighted.
- Let a colleague whose judgment he respects/trusts review your code. When that person is ok with your code put that in the email.
- Use language to nudge him to sign off your code.

So ideally your new email would be something like this.

> Hi boss,
> to implement feature X, I made the code changes you can see below. I already showed these changes to Jane and she thinks they are good. So I guess you are ok with them as well?

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do in this situation?

Keep sending him reminders (every few days, don't wait several weeks between reminders) and keep asking him what you should do while you wait. There isn't much else you can do to get him to review your work in my opinion. If he doesn't really have anything for you to do, you should probably use this time to try and improve your skills or try and work on other tasks (if there are any you can work on by yourself).

> Is he just busy or is he trying to get rid of me somehow?

We can't really answer that. It's likely that he's just busy, especially since he was recently promoted.